# Macro to look up a value

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this formula to look up a value in my table

```
=IF($A$1=1;VLOOKUP(B3;data_1;4);IF($A$1=2;VLOOKUP(B3;data_2;4);IF($A$1=3;VLOOKUP(B3;data_3;4);"")))
```

my problem is that code exist in many range, thats from B3:B25
We can meet that in 12 sheet, lets say (Sheet A, Sheet B, Sheet C , etc), and that make the file seem big & slowly. Is there any solution for me to simplify by using macro VBA code? i hope to get solution here, thanks.

Comment: What are you saying "data_x" is a sheet or a range, i would make sure that you are only looking in the relevant data, not the whole column, but i am not sure VBA would speed this up, you could use the IF in the VLOOKUP maybe?

Comment: Indirect might work, not sure how to word it though.`indirect("data_" & $A$1)` hopefully someone will read this and get it to work for you

Comment: The formula selects from 3 Defined Names. 1) Are these defined names in the same sheet where the formula goes? 2) Could tell us the addresses of these Defined Names? 3) What do you mean by "code exist in many ranges" and by "we can meet that in 12 sheets. 4) In what range this formula goes?   Need to know the answer to these question as to be able to determine what can be done to speed up performance... It will be even better if you could share your workbook...